# interrupt and resume long running ffmpeg encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, resume, suspend

When i have a longer high res video (full-hd or 4k) which are not compressed well, encoding to webm/vp9 can take very long even with a recent system due to the lack of hardware acceleration with webm/vp9.
Are there any options to interrupt an encoding with ffmpeg and resume which survives a reboot.
So i don't want to pause encoding using bg but save & stop encoding state and resume from there.

The next best thing i could think of is to split the source into smaller subsets (by time) and process them and stitch results together again. But this only allows predefined interruption points and requires the split & merge to be done in addition.
On the pro side it could allow parallel processing if multithreading is not using all available cores yet.

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/q/17061/

Answer (score -1):

Almost all operating systems have the possibility to suspend a process by sending a SIGTSTP signal. This signal can be caught by the process and it can choose to react differently to it, but I hardly think the ffmpeg team would say no to such good functionality for free.

I now tested it and it works fine. You can send the signal from the controlling terminal with ctrl-z or simply by executing "kill -SIGTSTP <pid of process>". This strategy usually work well in all os's I've tried to use it in, and can also be used for most other programs, not only ffmpeg.

This solution will likely have problem with the reboot in the middle, though. I think that some "sleep" modes might preserve processes and everything but I'm not sure. It's a bit of a tall order.

You could of course split your encoding into parts using flags to tell which part of the original you want that particular process to use. "ffmpeg -ss <start> -to <end> -i inputfile ..."

Obviously the start and end refer to times in the in-file. You can give the times as "HH:MM:SS". I expect other time formats might also be supported but I leave that research to somebody else.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I think the SIGTSTP is as you hinted not suited for a real reboot. Hibernate is not working  out (since switch to amd open source graphic drivers it does not work). And a suspend won't allow the OS switch i intend to do the reboot for.
Splitting i do and have scripted so i can easily do things like part1, part2 and then use concat for stitching it back. It is of course not as flexible as you need to know/decide upfront of the started encode to do it and when to split.
A real stop/resume would allow more adhoc reaction.

Comment: @simon What is the context here. Why do you have to interrupt it? Is it something that happens suddenly and without warning or is it more "OK, the computer room is closing for the evening, I have to log out"?

Comment: @simon If you have a modicum of advance notice you can use this strategy:

If you imagine the following algorithm (some kind of pseudocode, pythonlike):

`
global stop = False
for file in files_to_recode:
    if already_recoded(file):
        continue
    while not at end:
        code_next_10_min(file)
        if stop: exit(0)
    stitch_together(file)
    if stop: exit(0)
`

Comment: @simon Then you also have to register a signalhandler that reacts to e.g. SIGUSR2 and sets stop to True. Depending on language preferences signal handlers are covered in e.g. Chap 15 in the Camel Book (programming perl, 4e.), Chap 5 of Programming Python or read up on the trap command in your shell if that's what your using.

Comment: the context is i start encoding for a bunch of clips under linux. Then i want to switch OS to windows e.g. for gaming (not always planned to the hour - when one gets the chance). So OS changes and with that all which is not preserved to disk.
Suspend to disk was working with my old graphics card. Unfortunately i did not manage to get this working with the radeon yet.
I might try the x min stitching approach, currently time for scripting is short and it would depend on things like resolution as well. E.g. encoding 4k is quite slower than 720p ....

Comment: So the idea is to make little steps at a time such as coding a short bit of the file or merge all the files (probably doesn't take that long when you have  all the pieces). Then you have a choice of two things:
1 Be happy with the bits that were recoded and accept the loss of the relatively small file that is wasted. This might also require cleaning up some half written files.
2 Send a signal (e.g. with "kill" in your shell). Have your script (or whatever controls the recoding of snippets) react to the signal by exiting cleanly at the earliest opportune moment (and probably tell you so).